# Android Studio, change resource configuration

Tags: android, android-studio

I had created an XML layout, but by some mistake, I set its configuration to  (large-land). I want to remove that (large-land) configuration so that the layout can be used for other configurations.

If possible, I wanted to do it within the Android Studio, because in the future I might need to do similar thing, for example changing a (large-land) to (large-port). However, I could not find any menu regarding that. Is it possible? Or is it the only method to move the files in the operating system's file manager?

Answer (score 0):

You can right-click on the resource and click on move , which allows you to modify location of the resource file, during which you can rename to resource to correct configuration and click Ok.